# Разбить время выполнения скрипта, не изменяя параметров ini.php

Tags: php, phpexcel

Здравствуйте!

Есть долгая по времени выполнения задача (скрипт), вследствие этого, задачу необходимо разделить по времени, чтобы не произошло исключения [Maximum execution time of N seconds]

Ограничения такие: нельзя изменять параметры ini.php

Есть мысли такие: замерить максимально-допустимое выполнение скрипта, затем при достижении этого времени перезапустить эту же страницу передав необходимые параметры в виде GET запроса (число итерации, к примеру).

Но правилен ли такой подход? Быть может есть другие способы?

Comment: нельзя изменять параметры ini.php - нельзя изменять файл или нельзя изменить параметры для скрипта? Если второе, то почему?

Comment: Просто разбейте запись в файл (если это phpexcel) на разные куски.

Comment: @A. Eldon несколько дней назад я на работе писал экспортёр данных в csv-файл из бд. Там как раз реализовано разбиение по частям, т.к. во первых, из-за большого объёма скрипт упирался в ограничение по памяти, и во вторых - по времени выполнения. Если вы сможете разобраться в моём коде, чтобы подправить его под свой скрипт, то я опубликую решение. Но на подробное описание у меня времени сейчас нет.

Comment: @splash58 Спасибо за ответ. Ни то, ни другое. Дали именно такую задачу. Возможно, чтобы скрипт не съел всю выделенную память. Конечно, в таком случае можно изменить параметр "memory_limit", но тогда весь сайт из-за скрипта будет подвисать

Comment: @Эдуард спасибо за ответ. Было бы здорово посмотреть, возможно и разберусь

Comment: @lampa Спасибо за ответ. Не совсем понял, что вы предлагаете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// Экспорт из БД в csv

// Запись имён полей: 1-вкл; 0-выкл;
$add_field_names = 1;

$key = isset($_GET['key']) ? (int) $_GET['key'] : 0;
$key != 0 ?: $_SESSION['i'] = 0;

// Массив с названиями таблиц
$tables = include 'show_tables.php';

if (!empty($tables[$key])) {
    $dir = 'temp';
    is_dir($dir) ?: mkdir($dir, 0777);

    $table_name = $tables[$key];
    $csv = $dir . '/' . $table_name . '.csv';
    $fp = fopen($csv,'w');

    $query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS `all` FROM ' . $table_name;
    $result = sql_query($query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    mysqli_free_result($result);

    $offset = 0;
    $rows = 10000;

    $num_rows = 0;
    $all = $row['all'];
    $all <= $rows ?: $num_rows = intval($all / $rows);

    do {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $table_name . ' LIMIT ' . $offset . ', ' . $rows;
        $result = sql_query($query);

        $fields = [];
        $int = 0;

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $lines = [];
            foreach ($row as $field => $line) {
                if ($add_field_names && !in_array($field, $fields)) {
                    $fields[] = $field;
                }
                $lines[] = '\'' . $line . '\'';
            }
            // Запись имён полей в первую строку
            if (!empty($fields) && $int < 1 && $offset < 1) {
                fputcsv($fp, $fields, ';') < 1 ?: ++$int;
            }

            fputcsv($fp, $lines, ';') < 1 ?: ++$int;
        }

        $offset += $rows;

    } while (--$num_rows > 0);

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    fclose($fp);

    ++$key;

    if (isset($tables[$key])) {
        header('Refresh:0; url=?key=' . $key);
    }
}

// Блок для просмотра в браузере (закоментарить для крона)
$cnt = function ($int) {
    isset($_SESSION['i']) ?: $_SESSION['i'] = 0;
    return $_SESSION['i'] += $int;
};

echo 'Экспортировано таблиц: <b>'. $key .'</b><br>Всего строк: <b>' . $cnt($int) . '</b>';
```

Comment: @A. Eldon запостил ответ. Там надо подкорректировать функции для работы с БД, и добавить старт сессий _(если нужен счётчик)_, т.к. они у меня были в подключаемых файлах от моего движка _(я их удалил по понятным причинам)_

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать  `set_time_limit(0)`;
Но 
`set_time_limit()` не действует, если PHP запущен в режиме safe mode.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но параметры тоже нельзя изменять